# conversion from jdbc to open jpa

Tags: jpa, jdbc

I am new to open jpa environment , and i need to convert jdbc code to open jpa , please help me out with this problem . i am posting the jdbc code with this post.

```
//error.java//
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class ErrorDAO
{

DataConnection jdbcConnection = null;

public ErrorDAO()
{
    jdbcConnection = new DataConnection();  

}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ErrorDAO errorDAO = new ErrorDAO();
    long errid = errorDAO.getErrorId("POTENTIAL VIOLATION");
    String[] details = errorDAO.getErrorDetails(errid);

    System.out.println(details[0]);
    System.out.println(details[1]);

}


public String[] getErrorDetails(long errid)
{
    String[] details = new String[2];
    System.out.println("The input error id = " + errid);

    try {
        Connection connection = jdbcConnection.getConnectionInstance();
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM VARBALAS.ERROR_MASTER WHERE ERRORID = "+errid;
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next())
        {
            details[0] = rs.getString("ERRDESC");
            details[1] = rs.getString("SEVERITY");


        }
       rs.close();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return details;
}



public long getErrorId(String errDesc)
{
    long errid = 0 ;
    try {
        Connection connection = jdbcConnection.getConnectionInstance();
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT ERRORID FROM VARBALAS.ERROR_MASTER WHERE ERRDESC = '"+errDesc+"'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next())
        {
            errid = rs.getLong("ERRORID");

        }
        System.out.println("Printing the queried ERROR id "+errid);

        System.out.println("End of Data");
        rs.close();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    return errid;
}

}
```

Comment: What are you having difficulty with; Setting up entities, converting queries to JPA, managing transactions, etc?

Comment: @JohnKane : i am finding it difficult in converting query to jpa.

Comment: I updated my answer, their documentation is pretty decent. They walk you through pretty much whatever is needed.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.1/apache-openjpa/docs/main.html) is their documentation and it seems like it gives a decent description of how to use it. [Here](http://openjpa.apache.org/samples.html), is a link to some of their samples.

For examples of using JPA queries, take a look at Section 10 from the above documentation link.

a quick example  (from their documentation)could be something like:

```
EntityManager em=...
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM Magazine x");
List<Magazine> results = (List<Magazine>) q.getResultList();
```